# NSData from dataWithContentsofURL has a specific key/value pair null

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I'm attempting to parse some html off a specific site.

I grab all the content from the site and save it as NSData with this line.

```
NSData *testData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somewebsite/"]];
```

I use TFHipple Scraper to go through every single element in the HTML, which works fine. I can see everything.

When I get to the specific element I'm looking it for, it has 5 key/value pairs as expected, verified with dev tools on the site. The scraper see's the first four and their correct values just fine.

Here's the problem, when it gets to the last key/value pair, "href" it's always null. This contains the link I'm trying to extract.

A colleague suggested that maybe some JS is injecting the link after the page loads, but I couldn't find anything to support that idea.

Any idea why "href" would be null but everything else is perfectly loaded?

Comment: What do you see for the href when you download that URL on the command line using `curl` or `wget`? (Can you post the relevant excerpt?)

Comment: @AaronBrager I haven't downloaded with either on command line, will try that now. In Xcode it's "" empty.

Comment: @AaronBrager curl just revealed a ton of interesting information. I think I know why it isn't working. Look at this snippet, tell me what you think [link](http://pastebin.com/wymn6AG8)

Comment: That looks like JavaScript which I don't think TFHipple will parse. You could try using JavaScriptCore.

Comment: @AaronBrager You're right. I just re-created their get request and am generating the URL myself now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response data looks like JavaScript, not HTML. I don't think TFHipple will parse that. You could try using JavaScriptCore. NSHipster has [a really good writeup on it](http://nshipster.com/javascriptcore/).

Comment: Reviewed the actual Javascript after doing a curl call in terminal as @AaronBrager suggested, they're creating and appending the link there. That's why dataWithContentsofURL wasn't not seeing it. It doesn't execute any javascript so that value is never generated. I ended up just building the GET request myself and then building the download link with the response.